# How to get coords that are relative to the xy axis of a plane with arbitrary rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

Given a random point on a plane which has an arbitrary rotation, how could I get the xy coords of that point relative to the xy axis on the plane, assuming I call an arbitrary point on the plane the origin? I can get the absolute xyz coords of that point in worldspace (using raycast), but the relative coords has me stumped.

Comment: There can be infinitely many orientations of these x-y axes on the plane; you need another parameter to specify which.

Comment: @spug the xy axis orientation that matches the xy axis of the camera, when it is looking at right angles to the plane.

Comment: what about when it isn't looking at right angles? do you just mean the axes of the camera projected on to the plane at any angle? and by "raycast" do you mean converting screen coordinates to world coordinates by calculating the correct camera ray?

Comment: because when you project the camera axes on a plane at an arbitrary angle, the axes do not form an orthogonal basis (i.e. your projected x-y axes will not be at 90 degrees), so when you change camera angles the coordinates change meaning, and it would be very hard to do anything useful with them.

Comment: @spug yes I suppose I wasn't exactly clear on that point. Assume a plane instantiated directly in front of the camera (new Plane(ray.direction,ray.GetPoint(distance_from_camera_face)), and the camera having an arbitrary position/rotation (except for its z rotation, z=0). This is a plane struct btw, not a plane primitive created in the editor.

Comment: @spug To be more clear, the plane would be instantiated once, in front of the camera with a given  transform. The plane would not follow the camera view.

Comment: but what is `ray.direction`? do you mean `camera.direction`? in that case the axes would just be the camera's right and up axes at the time of initialization, and they *would* be orthogonal. calculating the in-plane coordinate in that case would be as trivial as finding the dot-product with those vectors

Comment: @spug sorry again. Yes, ray.direction as in camera ray direction, where ray=Camera.main.ViewportPointtoRay(new Vector3(0.5,05,0)). I will definitely have a look at screen coordinates, and the dot-product,

Comment: @spug Finally had a chance to implement some of your suggestions. Your idea of using screen coordinates will work. If you want, post your response as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if now I understood it correctly. You use a raycast from the camera to hit a point on a plane. The raycast returns a world position, but you want a local position instead (and with an origin different than 0,0?). The InverseTransformPoint can do just that.
The code below uses the mouse to select a screen point and creates a raycast to get the local position of the hit point relative to the object hit.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray r = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(r,out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point)); // point relative to local (0,0)
                Debug.Log(hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point- new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0)));// local point with origin as local (0.5,0.5)
            }
        }
```

---

[Old Answer]

If I understood your question correctly you would like to get the world position relative to the local position in that plane. To do that you can use the plane's transform. The method [Transform.TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) can be used to transform the local position to world position.

The example below uses a local position relative to the object and gets the world position in the update method. If you rotate the plane while the game is running it will change the world position relative to the local position.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 localPos;
    public Vector3 worldPos;

    void Update()
    {
        worldPos = transform.TransformPoint(localPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so place an object at my arbitrary origin, then place one at my random point, then use InverseTransformPoint  to get the position of the random object relative to the origin object? I'll try it.

Comment: that is another way you can do it. I was thinking something more like a random point Vector3 localPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0, Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f)); relative to the plane and use the TransformPoint to get the world position of that random point. You can use it to instantiate an object or other thing you might need.

Comment: TransformPoint --> Local position to World position || InverseTransformPoint --> World position to Local position

Comment: I found that this isn't quite what I'm looking for. The relative coord is still an absolute worldspace coord, where the "relative to" point (the planes "origin") is translated to worldspace origin (ie drawing a line along an axis on the plane changes x and y).

Comment: Just saw your updates. I think that if you take the raycast hit point and transform with plane.transform.InverseTransformPoint you will get the relative local position with origin in local (0,0). If you need a position relative to other origin you can subtract that origin from the result.

Comment: your updated answer is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you. User spug made a similar suggestion in the OP comments. I told spug I would credit his/her answer if they posted it, so let me give spug a little longer to respond. If not, I will be happy to accept your answer.